# DB Defaults to SQLite3 on DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, environment-variables, production-environment, digital-ocean

I'm having trouble setting up my rails app on digital ocean (w/ubuntu&nginx&passenger).  My app won't connect to the postgresql db on DO and seems to default to SQLite3 for some reason. In my local environment everything is fine and connects to postgresql but at DO this error pops up in the browser:

`"SQLite3::CantOpenException".`

I'm sort of new to configuring environments, but I added this to the .bashrc file, thinking maybe this is why it's not working, but the following line of code does nothing:

`export APP_ENV="production"`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, when I created the app I even did it like this:

`rails new myproject -T -d postgresql`

I also read a tutorial that advised me to just put my password into my app, but that seems like a completely ridiculous thing to do.  I'm pretty sure I need to set up environment variables but I thought that this is what the postgresql at the end of "rails new myproject -T -d postgresql" does...I'm lost.

Comment: Are you using a the default Rails Server (rails s) to launch your application or you deployed a passenger-nginx/apache environment?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I'm using passenger.  I predominantly followed this tutorial [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the NGINX explanation:

http://linux.ioerror.us/2014/02/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf/

Or you might have to set the env variables inside NGINX config file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   set $ENV_app "production";
}
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/wiki/Nginx-Configuration-Settings-and-Environment-Variables

Comment: I'm not sure this would work cuz I'm using nginx ;|  but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Edited with nginx configuration example.